# Unable to SSH after enforcing SELinux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, debian, selinux

We have an ubuntu VM on Azure. We replaced AppArmor with SELinux using Debian packages (`selinux-basics_0.5.2_all.deb` & `selinux-policy-default_2.20140421-9_all.deb`).

Everything works well when selinux is in `permissive` mode but as soon as we change mode to `enforcing` we are unable to ssh.

I've tried to `autorelabel` but it didn't help.

I'm new to SELinux and couldn't find where it gone wrong.

Please find the audit logs below:

```
pam_systemd(sshd:session): Failed to create session: Connection timed out
pam_selinux(sshd:session): Unable to get valid context for <user>
error: ssh_selinux_getctxbyname: Failed to get default SELinux security context for <user>
error: ssh_selinux_getctxbyname: Failed to get default SELinux security context for <user>
error: ssh_selinux_setup_pty: security_compute_relabel: Invalid argument
```

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing policycoreutils  and use audit2allow to create an appropriate rule for ssh.

Audit2allow looks at the audit.log file (or whatever file you specify with the log of problem ssh selinux lines) and creates a set of rules you can apply to fix it.

See the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/audit2allow.1.html) for more details on exact usage.